# What is my SSRS URL to run a report directly supplying parameters with an INSTANCE name

Tags: web, url, reporting-services

What is my URL to run a report via an web app when my instance name is ReportsPROD_AU. I tried ReportServer_PROD_AU, ReportServerPROD_AU, ReportServerPRODAU and other variations. If I cannot log onto the server box how I figure this out - what is the convention?

Answer (score 0):

I did find the answer by unconventional means, I figured out the SSRS server name and I had permission to logon to SQL Server and it had a list of database names like ReportServer and ReportServer2 and few others and tried them all until one of database names worked for URL - happy days.